# why does Microsoft Graph require $select with $expand=extensions?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In the Graph Explorer, when I authenticate and use the "get an open extension" sample, it does a GET against this endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,displayName,mail,mobilePhone&$expand=extensions
```

That returns any extensions I've added with the "create an open extension" sample. But if I remove the $select parameter so that the endpoint looks like this ...

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=extensions
```

... then I get an error stating that ""The entity instance value of type 'microsoft.graph.user' doesn't have a value for property 'id'." It seems I need to have a $select parameter to return the expanded extensions. And it doesn't matter what the $select value is - I can use a nonsensical string that doesn't correspond to any fields in the JSON payload, and it works fine.

Why is a $select parameter required in this case?

Comment: Hey Doug, can you share the nonsensical string example? I can definitely put nonsensical strings in the select clause (which is a bug), but it requires me to put id in there explicitly.

Comment: Hey Mark, here's an example of a request that works fine for returning the extensions I've added to my user node:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=fieldnotfound&$expand=extensions

I get the error noted above if I don't include the $select, but adding $select=fieldnotfound makes it work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to replicate this with exception of `$select=fieldnotfound`. I get the same error returned with or without that $select statement. I can't explain why this you're seeing that behavior but I can provide some insight into what is going wrong here.

First a little background on what is happening under the covers.

When you call `/me` with no additional params, a default `$select` parameter is used automatically. By default it uses the following:

`$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id`

As you can see, `id` is in fact one of the selected fields. In theory, simply adding `$expand=extentions` should therefore work as expected. Unfortunately it seems that adding `$expand` also slightly changes the fields in underlying `$select` statement as well. Namely, it drops the `id` field:

`$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName`

If I use specify both however, it works as expected:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id&$expand=extensions`

I suspect this is a bug around the default field select but I'll defer to the Graph team on that. The above query should at least allow you to move forward in the meantime.