# MS Graph Get User with Expand=Extensions return status 500

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Getting the user just passing the user id works fine:

```
const { data: response } = await axios.get(`${ MS_GRAPH_USER_API }/${ id }`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${ TOKEN }`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
```

However, this:

```
const { data: response } = await axios.get(`${ MS_GRAPH_USER_API }/${ id }?$expand=extensions`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${ TOKEN }`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
```

returns the following error:

data: '{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(extensions())/$entity"{\r\n' +
'  "error": {\r\n' +
'    "code": "InternalServerError",\r\n' +
    `"message": "The entity instance value of type 'microsoft.graph.user' doesn't have a value for property 'id'. To compute an entity's metadata, its key and concurrency-token property values must be provided.",\r\n` +
'    "innerError": {\r\n' +
'      "date": "2020-12-19T09:51:26",\r\n' +
'      "request-id": "93cf5d97-0096-4769-871e-f8fcf7cd17c3",\r\n' +
'      "client-request-id": "93cf5d97-0096-4769-871e-f8fcf7cd17c3"\r\n' +
'    }\r\n' +
'  }\r\n' +
'}'

Why is that? The user has an extension added to his/her profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to include a select clause in the URL before the expand clause, i.e.:

$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id&$expand=extensions

just had to try a few different google searches before finding this:

[why does Microsoft Graph require $select with $expand=extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558878/why-does-microsoft-graph-require-select-with-expand-extensions)